# Better way to say "No bulls--t"

Tags: phrase-request

I'm the person who like concise, and don't like the literature style stuffing in lots of irrelevant information to distract you from the main idea. So when I saw a book called *"No bullshit Java"*, I know that's exactly the kind of writing style I prefer, both reading and writing.

However, that *"No bullshit"* is kind of stronger than my tolerance. Is there a better phrase that can convey the idea that I don't like those "bullshit", but not as strong?

Example usage:

> I read a very useful blog, but there are so many distraction there that it is very easy to miss a step. So I'm documenting it again in my (no-)____ style.

PS. I know I can use the word "*concise*", but I do want it to be more vivid than that, but not as colorful as "No bullshit". :-)

Comment: Maybe "no bull"?

Comment: "Concise" and "no bullshit" are not opposites. "Concise" means using a small number of words to express an idea; "no bullshit" means that the description is accurate, as well as that it doesn't contain unnecessary things. So, for example, I could write a perfectly concise explanation of how the world is flat, but it would be total bullshit.

Comment: Note sure about your tolerance levels, but *bovine waste* may or may not be inside.

Comment: @Dav Bullshit *can* be the opposite of concise. Sense 2. Merriam-Webster is *discursive.* And that's what we'd expect the title of the book mentioned to mean: Doubtfully that other books on Java contain lies/inaccuracies. More likely that they contain fluff while this one provides what's essential.

Comment: @JimReynolds I agree that I should have said that "concise" and "no bullshit" are _not necessarily_ opposites. And I've read plenty of programming books that contain things that were inadvisable or even flat-out wrong, so I'd interpret "no bullshit" to mean both "no fluff" and "no garbage" in this context.

Comment: @Dav Ah, yes. There are multiple senses of *bullshit,* of course not unrelated. They are all bullsit, after all!

Comment: @JimReynolds That's bullshit!  Er, I mean, that's how bullshit is, not that's an example of bullshit. :-)

Comment: In the specific case of programming guides, *practical* or *pragmatic* are appropriate, though in other contexts these would not be suitable alternatives.

Comment: to name a few: crap, excrement, poor quality and so on

Comment: "to-the-point" perhaps?

Comment: plain English, please.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Phrases which you might be interested in are

> **to the point** style
>   **no frills** style
>   **no nonsense** style
>   **no sugar** style *( sugar these days has a computer technical meaning of frivolous )*
>   **unsweetened** style *( a play on sugar )*

**Concise** only means **short** or **compact** and could still have sugar

Comment: No nonsense is the best (in my opinion) - it has nice alliteration as well.

Comment: _No nonsense_ is the closest synonym in UK English

Comment: Not heard this "no sugar/unsweetened" phrase before, and not found any reference on google, got any examples?

Comment: In the context of programming, *sugar* is usually a positive term, e.g. *syntactic sugar*. I wouldn't say it means *frivolous*, which is more negative.

Comment: *No nonsense* is a great phrase here, as it conveys a "Straight to the point, no being distracted by side-points, professional" image

Comment: Thanks everyone for the response. I'm picking the obvious winner. Indeed most people would agree that *No nonsense*  is the best, with a nice alliteration. I did hope that *"no sugar"* can spread from the dietary domain, carrying the same meaning as "no frivolous" into the computer world. I will start promoting it. Thanks again!

Comment: I don't think "no sugar" is used but "no sugar coating" is. Don't think "unsweetened" is used either.

Comment: I don't know the exact origin, but my guess is that using **sugar** as a computer technical adjective may be an expansion of [**syntactic sugar**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar). Also, most native speakers will know that **sugar** can be used as an expletive substituting for sh*t. I've only heard "no sugar coating" in regular speech not related to computers.

Comment: I haven't heard of "no-sugar" before, but I HAVE heard "don't sugar-coat it".  No-nonsense is the best substitution for no-bullshit.

Comment: Once again - sugar in a technical computing sense is nothing to do with frivolousness.

Answer (score 28):

Two common ways of communicating the same meaning in politer terms could be:

- **No nonsense** style...
- **No fuss** style ....

You could (at a pinch) say:

- I'm documenting again without so much **bull**.

The latter leaves the listener/reader to mentally add the missing expletive.

Comment: "No nonsense" is an excellent suggestion. But I would say that "bull" is essentially the same register as "bullshit", in that the expletive is so strongly implied that omitting it doesn't make the statement any more polite.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Or as [Louis CK would say](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dF1NUposXVQ), you're actually making the statement **less** polite, since you're putting the burden of creating the expletive on the listener. :-) In general though it saddens me that we have a culture where a word describing poop is "bad" (or TBH that "expletives" exist in general).

Comment: @The If there was no expletive, we would have created one.

Comment: @The111: I think it's great. It would be extremely tedious if every word had equal "weight". If "expletives" weren't "expletives" then I guarantee they wouldn't be used as often — surely the whole point of using the worst ones is that it gives a sort of emotional satisfaction at a time when you need it the most? Otherwise we might as well just drop all the synonyms of things :)

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the very good suggestions from the earlier answers (*no nonsense* being my favorite), I'd suggest the simple

- **essential**
- **direct**
- **straight**
- **plain**
- **compact**.

*Essential* is actually not uncommon in computer literature titles ("Essential Java"), but it goes beyond style; while one would certainly expect no poetry in such a book, it is additionally a statement about the (limited) scope.

I'm not sure whether *straight* may make some silly highschool students think of sexual orientation: "*Straight* Java as opposed to what? Queer Java?"

I find *plain* pretty nice because of the usual context in which it is used (plain talk, plain truth) but it may be too much of an understatement.

J.R.'s comment **distilled** is also interesting (and O'Reilly's famous "in a Nutshell" series means basically that, even though "in a Shot Glass" would fit "distilled" better).

*Compact* was inspired by J.R.'s *distilled.* Short form usually implies "no frills".

Another line of thought focuses on the dishonesty implied when calling something "bullshit". Often a user (let alone buyer) feels betrayed. There are words which focus on that aspect:

- **honest**
- **genuine**

Yet another aspect of bullshit is the lack in usability, leading to a few other options:

- **high-impact**
- **valuable**, **high-value**, **value-generating** etc.
- **indispensible**

These focus more on contents than on style or intent, but in order to be important the amount of irrelevant or wrong information must be pretty limited.

Comment: Beyond being an understatement, "plain" might suggest "basic" but a definite +1 for the other suggestions.

Comment: Your suggestions remind me of another word I've frequently seen in computer science: _distilled_ (although the word _distilled_ is usually positioned AFTER the word it modifies, as in [this blog post](http://www.verycomputer.com/143_5267fb3689fca64c_1.htm)).

Answer (score 3):

There are [many](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english-thesaurus/drivel) [synonyms](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/bullshit?s=ts) you could use, but I would suggest:

- no [baloney](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/baloney#baloney__3)
- no [hot air](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hot-air#hot-air__2) - 
  this ons is more colourful, and might fit because it means:

> **Empty talk** that is intended to impress

(from ODO, emph. mine).

Since you are trying to convey that there are no unnecessary words that serve no real purpose (i.e. empty talk) I would go for this one.

---

Aside: you might find this ELU post interesting: [What is the source of the phrase “phony baloney”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/203937/what-is-the-source-of-the-phrase-phony-baloney)

Comment: Just a comment that "baloney" is quite (North?) American.

Answer (score 2):

"Forthright" seems to fit in your sample sentence.  partial def - adjective
1.
(of a person or their manner or speech) direct and outspoken; straightforward and honest.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for something that is still informal but not as crude, I would go with

> Straight Dope - n. the plain, unvarnished truth

Answer (score 0):

First, what does "no bullshit" mean? **Honest** and **direct**.

**No nonsense** seems good, but doesn't really convey the lack of deception.

**No bull** is a great version, because it can be short for euphemisms like "bulldust".

Depending on whether the phrase needs to fit into the same sentence, "____ Java", then these might work:

- **No kidding**
- **No mucking around**
- **No joke**
- **Straight up**

Answer (score 0):

Not a native speaker, but perhaps:

**down to the nitty-gritty** - reduced to the max, essentials only

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the answer with "short and sweet" got deleted. That might not be the "best" option, but it certainly works:

[From the FreeDictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/short+and+sweet):

> **Adj. 1.  short and sweet** - dealt with very quickly; to the point; *"the conference was short and sweet"; "make your statement short and sweet"*

Answer (score 0):

Brief, clear writing can be called *succinct* ([OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/succinct)). It's a particularly good choice here because it's especially applicable to writing. You might even say it's the most... *succinct*... answer.